# How do I prevent Google Compute from creating new users when creating a new instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, packer

I am using Packer to generate an image on the Google Cloud Platform. I want to use this image to create pre-provisioned instances that are configured for our build pipeline and projects.

As part of my provisioning, I set up a bunch of users and associated SSH keys. Most, if not all, of these users, already exist within GCP, and when the build instance is spun up the `/home` directory is already filled with user home directories (presumably GCP users). this is fine, my provisioning process merely adds some files and authorizes some SSH keys.

I debugged Packer's build process by SSH'ing into the build instance Packer created (using the same SSH key Packer is using) and manually verified each step completed as expected – it did. The relevant user home directories were there and contained the correct files as well as had the right keys set in `authorized_keys`. Furthermore, I verified each user's SSH configuration was valid by SSH'ing into the machine using that user's username and key – also worked.

At the end of the build process, my user directories are exactly how I want them to be, and each user could access the instance no problem. Packer completes its job, saves a snapshot, and destroys the build instance.

However, when I create a new instance from the image my user directories are bulldozed, I think (I can't actually access this new instance using the SSH users and keys I previously provisioned). I assume that GCP has *helpfully* bulldozed my `/home` directory and set it up again, erasing the changes made during provisioning.

Am I correct in this assumption (I can't connect to actually verify it), and if so is there a way I can instruct GCP to *not* set up users?

I have tried `blocking project wide keys` but that didn't seem to make a difference.

I don't think this is a Packer problem, but perhaps some metadata can be set when creating the instances?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

This was a two part problem: part missing a [nuance in the docs](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/googlecompute.html#metadata) and part face-palm.

- Nuance: When setting `block-project-ssh-keys` the value must be `"true"`, and not `true`.
- Face-palm: Use the right image when you create a new instance.